# whats the mobilenetwork-manager equivalent of the WifiManager

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

I need to add an action to an IntentFilter for detecting changes in the mobile-network.. so basically what I need is an equivalent of `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` but for the MobileNetwork. but I'm not really sure what the class I'm looking for is called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) would help. It has some description in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html). Briefly, I think You need to:

- Register `BroadcastReceiver` with `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`
- Check changed network(or all connections)